# Catch popup when opening URI with NSWorkspace.openURL

Tags: macos

I'm trying to use [NSWorkspace.openURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openURL:) to open a url with a custom scheme.

If that application exists on the Mac, that method returns `true` and it opens the app just fine.

If that application does not exist on the machine, it returns `false`, but it also pops up what looks to be a Mac window saying "There is no application set to open the URL {my url}"  and then gives the option to search in the Mac app store.

Is there any way to prevent this popup from happening?  Since my application can handle the return `false` value from the method, and that popup is sending the user down the wrong path.

Something similar to [UIApplication.canOpenUrl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:) (UIApplication is only available in ios, not osx)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to use LaunchService.  Documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/index.html

Comment: I wonder if there is something similar for the web, to prevent this popup in a browser?